# Testing a SD card?

Tags: sd-card, micro-sd-card

I am suspecting that one of my 32GB cards might be damaged - I would like to analyze it. Is there some free software to run an analysis of an SD card?

Comment: Is this a new SD Card or one that has been used before ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Windows, you can run `CHKDSK` on it with a surface scan.  If you are running Linux, use `badblocks`.  These utilities perform block-by-block analysis of the device to detect any damaged blocks.

Answer (score 1):

> I am suspecting that one of my 32 GB cards might be damaged - I would like to >analyze it. Is there some free software to run an analysis of an SD card?

I am having the same problem. I can not put more them 4.4 GB of data on the SD card. I tried SDFormatterv4, I used Windows, properties, format, extFat. Still have problems. I got Mini Tool Partition Wizard v8. I did a scan and at 13%, I got red block errors for the rest of the SD card. I Wiped the disk, Create Partition, Automatically It's a Logical Partition, I can name the partition, I set to ext. I did this process twice. On the 2nd time, the surface scan is now going Green blocks for the rest of the SD card.  I suggest you try Mini Tool Partition v8.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this: http://mympx.org/Downloads/p13_sectionid/2/p13_fileid/13